# Wireshark capture Magic Packet configuration

Tags: wireshark, packets, wake-on-lan

I have a laptop running Wireshark.  I'd like to find out how to configure wireshark to capture Magic Packets.

I have selected the interface, options, Capture filter, host 192.168.168.19 , Ok, Start on the laptop.

Laptop is IP 192.168.168.14.  I want to start up a PC at 192.168.168.19.

I have a program that sends out the Magic Packets called WON Magic Packet Sender.  I run it and select send.  I don't see anything captured in Wireshark.  I have another program called VNC control.  I select Wake Up.  I get a message saying The WakeUp signal is sent.  I still don't get anything captured in Wireshark.  I remove the capture filter in Wireshark.  I start the capture.  I get everything on the network.  I add a filter:

```
ip.src == 192.168.168.19 and ip.dst == 192.168.168.19
```

I get nothing captured after running both programs.
I removed the last filter and added a new filter:

```
ip.addr == 192.168.168.19
```

I get nothing captured after running both programs.

How can I configure Wireshark to capture the magic packets?

Comment: I don't think that this is a question stackoverflow deals with.

Comment: Wake-on-LAN uses raw Ethernet protocol, not IP. So if you filter on the IP address, you won't see it, since there's no IP header in the packet. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN

Comment: Um: The referenced Wikipedia article actually says:

"Since the magic packet is only scanned for the string above, and not actually parsed by a full protocol stack, it may be sent as any network- and transport-layer protocol, although it is typically sent as a UDP datagram to port 7 or 9, or directly over Ethernet as EtherType 0x0842".



So: the packet *could* have an IP header and, if so, the ip destination address might be 255.255.255.255

Answer (score 1):

Home I use "WOL" on filter, it's OK.

Sorry ten years to late    :-)

Answer (score 0):

Given the definition of the WON frame pattern (and not knowing how it is encapsulated), I would expect a *display* filter like the following to work:

`frame contains ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm`

where `mm:mm:mm:mm:mm:mm` is the MAC address of the destination PC (the one to which the WON messge is being sent).